# Play! 1.2.4 + Nginx load balancer - Unable to get two instances working together in PROD mode

Tags: nginx, playframework, load-balancing

I have implemented a Play! app with two different instances (let's say %inst1 and %inst2) in my server in order to avoid the downtime when precompiling with any update. I have configured nginx to get a load balancer. For each instance I have its own subdirectory and I have configured the file application.conf properly to get different ports for %inst1 and %inst2. The configuration file of nginx it's like that:

```
upstream myapp {
  server localhost:9031;
  server localhost:9032;
}

server {
  server_name www.example.com;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/myapp.access.log;

  location / {
    proxy_pass              http://myapp;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
  }
}
```

When I try this configuration in dev mode, it works perfectly. I execute both instance and whenever I stop one of them in order to update it, all the traffic goes to the other instance without any downtime. And when I restart again the app and reloads nginx, both instance are working perfectly.

The problem appears when I configured the instance for production mode. I only change the application.conf from:

```
%inst1.application.mode=dev
%inst2.application.mode=dev
```

to:

```
%inst1.application.mode=prod
%inst2.application.mode=prod
```

And then I'm not able to get both instance working at twice. Whenever I start the second one, I get a 502 Bad Gateway error. Then I check the status of the first instance and I get the following error:

```
$ play status --%inst1
~        _            _ 
~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
~ |_|            |__/   
~
~ play! 1.2.4, http://www.playframework.org
~ framework ID is inst1
~
~ Cannot contact the application...
~
```

Also, I cannot start it with an error like this:

```
Oops. /usr/share/apps/klingstore1 is already started! (or delete /usr/share/apps/klingstore1/server.pid)
```

Nor stop it:

```
Play was not running (Process id 11657 not found)
```

And I have to remove the server.pid manually. Then I start it again and it happens again with the other instance.

Do you have any clue?

Thanks!!

**SOLVED:**

Finally, it seems to be simply a problem of RAM. The instances are working correctly with the same configuration of Play! and Nginx during various days without problems.

Comment: I have a simmilar setup, which works without any issues. So I think it is something with your application.conf settings. It would be a great help if you could post it here.

Comment: Thanks, my application.conf seems to be fine. It works perfectly in my local laptop with as least 5 different instances. Now I'm trying some test, but I think it's working now and if it's true it seems to be a problem with a lack of RAM. I had more instances running of another heavy app. Now I have stopped them and it appears to be working. Maybe I was in the limit of available RAM and maybe the app in PROD mode requires a little bit more RAM. I will try a couple of days and update this post.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your logs/system.log file and see if there are some Exceptions prevent your play app from booting up

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention about logs. There is nothing unusual in logs files. Simply, like nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an addition to you `nginx.conf` rather than an answer, but I think it's a useful addition to this question.

If both of your instances are compiling, users get a 502 error. A better message would be "APPLICATION_NAME is being updated". This can be accomplished by setting a custon 502 error page:

**nginx.conf:**

```
error_page 502 /502.html;
location /502.html {
    index $uri;
}
```

**502.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>Kleiderliebe wird aktualisiert</title>
<style>body {margin: 0;padding: 0;background-color: #fff;color: #000;
        font-family: Arial,sans-serif;font-size: 14px;}
    #container {text-align: center;margin: 0 auto;padding: 20% 0;}</style>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10"></head>
<body><div id="container">
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,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" border="0">
<br/>YOUR_APPLICATION is being updated.<br/><br/>
<small>If this page does not refresh automatically, <a href="/">please click here</a>.
</small></div></body></html>
```

(the long data-URI is an animated spinner)